# TOC at the upper side of the beamer

Tags: beamer, sectioning

I have a code like this

```
  \documentclass{beamer}
  %\usetheme{Warsaw} 
  \usetheme{Montpellier}
  \title[Presentation 2018]
```

I want to have a TOC on every slide with current section highlated. I tried with

```
\AtBeginSection[]
{
\begin{frame}{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents[currentsection]
\end{frame}
}
```

But its not working on every slide I still have just Presentation 2018.

I marked my sections

```
\section{example}
```

Comment: How should the toc at the top of the slides be formatted? You could either use another theme or we could transplant the headline of another theme into `montpellier`. See https://hartwork.org/beamer-theme-matrix/ for an overview of available headlines, which one do you like? (don't worry about colours and such, they can all be adjusted) Maybe the `Szeged` theme could be used, it combines the lines like your theme but shows all sections at the top.

Comment: Wow Szeged is superb. Thank you! My I have 20+ slides so not all of them come at top, can I somehow deleted doubled ones?

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows which slides you want to delete?

Comment: Off-topic: the syntax `\title[Presentation 2018]` is wrong, it should be `\title{Presentation 2018}` or `\title[Presentation 2018]{Long version of the title}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I find customising the headline navigation the most difficult piece to change. So instead of changing the `Montpelier` theme, I suggest to use a theme with a headline navigation that meets your requirements and change the other elements of this theme as you like.

There even is a theme with headline navigation that looks very similar, the theme `Szeged`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Szeged}

\begin{document}

\section{section name 1}
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\section{section name 2}
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah I have ti like this, but because I have too many sections all of them doesn't fit in top frame. for example : https://imgur.com/a/vZpKEvr

Comment: @NoobProgrammer As said in my comment below your question, please make a MWE that shows how you managed to create the double entries, this is not the default behaviour.

Comment: I solved it its was \begin{frame} and after \section{blablabla}. Thank you so much :)

Comment: @NoobProgrammer You're welcome!